# Why metaclass __getattribute__ invoked here?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, attributes

Here is a code snippet retrieved from Python 2.7.12 documentation (**3.4.12. Special method lookup for new-style classes¶**):

> In addition to bypassing any instance attributes in the interest of
>   correctness, implicit special method lookup generally also bypasses
>   the `__getattribute__()` method even of the object’s metaclass:
>
> ```
> >>> class Meta(type):
> ...    def __getattribute__(*args):
> ...       print "Metaclass getattribute invoked"
> ...       return type.__getattribute__(*args)
> ...
> >>> class C(object):
> ...     __metaclass__ = Meta
> ...     def __len__(self):
> ...         return 10
> ...     def __getattribute__(*args):
> ...         print "Class getattribute invoked"
> ...         return object.__getattribute__(*args)
> ...
> >>> c = C()
> >>> c.__len__()                 # Explicit lookup via instance
> Class getattribute invoked
> 10
> >>> type(c).__len__(c)          # Explicit lookup via type
> Metaclass getattribute invoked
> 10
> >>> len(c)                      # Implicit lookup
> 10
> ```

My question is, why metaclass `__getattribute__` is invoked when executing `type(c).__len__(c)`?

Since `type(c)` yields `C`, this statement can be rewritten as `C.__len__(c)`. `C.__len__` is a unbound method defined in class `C`, and it can be found in `C.__dict__`, so why is `Meta` involved in the lookup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quotation from the same documentation, 3.4.2.1. More attribute access for new-style classes:

> `object.__getattribute__(self, name)`
>
> Called **unconditionally** to implement attribute accesses for
>   **instances** of the class. ...

Class `C` is an instance of metaclass `Meta`, so `Meta.__getattribute__` is called when `C.__len__` is accessed, even though the latter is can be found in `C.__dict__`.

In fact, accessing `C.__dict__` is also an attribute access, and thus `Meta.__getattribute__` would still be invoked.